# Can we have collapse-able content in the first section of a site FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

The [FAQ pages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) have very helpful 'show more'/'collapse' buttons to prevent overloading the visitor with detail.

This would be useful to have inside the first section ("What kind of questions can I ask here?") too - for example our [FAQ in progress](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-content-needs-to-go-in-the-main-site-faq-the-first-block/473#473) on the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site has bulleted lists with sub-lists that it would be nice to have hidden on first arrival.

Comment: That's really verbose.

Comment: And that is the way we want it - at least if the visitor wants to drill down into the detail. Also other faqs are long too and might benefit, eg http://english.stackexchange.com/faq, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the problem lies within the verbosity of the FAQ. What you've got here is what we commonly describe as the **"bulleted list from hell."** Okay, it hasn't *quite* reached those extremes, but the length seems to go beyond a use useful level of detail for a FAQ.

When a user first visits your site, **they want a succinct description** of what your site is about. That's all. They don't need a detailed, enumerated list of *everything* the site could possibly be about. You'll just keep adding, and adding, and adding to that list until it becomes new-user hostile: Your bulleted list from hell.

A site for "Database Administrators" says a lot. Sometimes those *"it's about… but **not** about"* sections helps clarify the most common *misunderstanding* users have about the site. But the FAQ really doesn't have become that long… unless the subject is inherently difficult to pin down. Try some simple English sentences to *describe* your subject rather than enumerating all possible topics exhaustively.

We *could* fold all that information into a header entry, but that would only hide the most important information users are looking for. If users don't see it at a glance, they will likely skip it completely. That's not good for your site.

Comment: We want the summary (eg "Advanced Querying") to be visable at all times, but the sub list ("Windowing functions", "Hierarchical data" ... ) to be collapsed by default. I fail to see how that would be "hid[ing] the most important information users are looking for". Only users specifically wanting to know whether their query counts as 'advanced' would ever expand the section.

Comment: @JackDouglas: Ah, I see. You want markup that allow further folding within the section itself. Sort of a *"herein lies more detail than you need."* I'm still not sure an annotated list is the best way to describe your scope, but at least I understand the nature of your [feature-request] now.

Comment: yippee :) FWIW we are exploring [an alternative using tags](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-content-needs-to-go-in-the-main-site-faq-the-first-block/473#473) that is at least better than the information overload we currently have (in our opinion that is :)